# Should view render menus or master pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I've developed my own custom users and roles objects using ActiveRecord that do NOT extend the default Asp.Net providers and therefore I can't get the user from the HttpContext. I can create a custom htmlhelper to render menus but should my views render the menu or the master page?

If it's the master page how can I pass to the custom htmlhelper things like current user since some menu items depend on the user roles.

Also, how can I detect what controller is being viewed inside my master pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If your menu functionality is supposed to exist on multiple pages, then it makes sense to put it in the master page. If not, then the normal view.

2) A popular choice is to make all of your ViewModels inherit from a base view class, and then your Master page uses that. Example:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<ViewBase>
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyViewModel>

public class MyViewModel : ViewBase { }
```

3) You can pull out the specific controller from the route data. However, if you need specific functionality for certain controllers, I would just suggest using a different master page for those views than trying to make all of your views use the same master page.

Comment: Your suggestion worked well because it forced me to go with completely strong typed view models for all my views.

Answer (score 1):

In general, all ASP.NET controls (whether WebForms or MVC) should control their own state.

In the case of handling navigation, I'd say create a .ASCX (partial view) and place it on your master page.  Let the partial view control how it is displayed based on the HttpContext.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did end up creating a partial view which will take care of rendering my menus. Its very sweet.